# How do I move files from one blob storage container to another blob storage container using powershell

Tags: powershell, azure

How do I move files in Azure from one storage container to another storage container. I have so far only come across options for copying blob but nothing comes up for move. I have tried Azcopy but no switch is there for moving files. also tried Start-AzureStorageBlobCopy

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Moving is the same as copy and then delete. So why not copy the blobs and then delete them on the original location? Making a general move command needs some type of distributed transaction, which is not easy to implement. Writing your own is a lot easier, because the blobstorage accounts are your own.